# CancellationToken and Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a couple of calls that I need to cancel a subscription based on a CancellationToken.  I saw [How to cancel an observable sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759833/how-to-cancel-an-observable-sequence) but I needed a more generic way.  I created an extension method that seems to work.

```
public static IObservable<TSource> TakeUntil<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source, CancellationToken token)
{

    var cancelationObservable =
        Observable.Create<object>(observer => token.Register(() => observer.OnNext(null)));
    return source.TakeUntil(cancelationObservable);
}
```

Is there a built in way of Rx to cover this?  Is Observable.Create the best way to trigger the pulse?

This seems so basic that I feel I may be missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to cancel a subscription

If you're actually subscribing to the source using `Subscribe()`, then that has overloads that accept a `CancellationToken`, you might want to consider using that.

---

```
Observable.Create<object>(observer => token.Register(() => observer.OnNext(null)));
```

It took me a while to figure out that this *doesn't* cause a memory leak. I thought that since you call `Register()`, but never use the returned `IDisposable` to unregister, the registrations will stay there even when they are no longer needed. But that's not true, because the `IDisposable` is actually returned to `Create()`, which will `Dispose()` it when it's no longer needed.

I think this is confusing enough that it warrants a comment explaining the situation.

Also, the common way to express the `void` type in generics in Rx is the `Unit` type, not `object`:

```
Observable.Create<Unit>(observer => token.Register(() => observer.OnNext(Unit.Default)));
```

This is longer than your code, but I think it's also clearer.

Comment: Thanks.  I checked the source code for the subscribe with cancellationtoken and they are doing something very similar.  I was concerned over the Cancel(true) that it's possible to not unsubscribe if the previous call back threw but MS isn't handling that case as well.